Entity Framework Core: query across multiple many-to-many navigation properties
I need some help creating "inner joins" across multiple, many-to-many navigation properties. The goal is for the TasksController to return a list of tasks assigned to the logged-in user.
Task has a 1-to-1 navigation property to Project. Project has a many-to-many relationship to Group with a derived join entity. Group has a many-to-many relationship to User also with a derived join entity.
public class Task 
{
    public int? ProjectID
    public Project Project
}

public class Project 
{
    public ICollection<Group> ProjectGroups
    public ICollection<Task> ProjectTasks
}

public class Group 
{
    public ICollection<Project> GroupProjects
    public ICollection<User> GroupMembers
}

public class User 
{
    public ICollection<Group> GroupMemberships
}

If I use .Include and .ThenInclude, the query returns results, but it creates LEFT JOINs which doesn't filter the results by the user...
var tasks = from t in _context.Task
                              .Include(t => t.Project)
                              .ThenInclude(p => p.ProjectGroups)
                              .ThenInclude(g => g.GroupMembers.Where(u => u.Login == "username"))
            select t;

If I use .Join, that will create the INNER JOIN, but I can't figure out how to bridge the many-to-many relationships...
var tasks = from t in _context.Task
            // This works fine
            .Join(_context.Project, 
                  task => task.ProjectID, 
                  project => project.ID, 
                  (task, project) => new { Task = task, Project = project }
                 ) 
            // This does not, can't figure out how to get from the ProjectGroups collection to Group
            .Join(_context.Group, 
                  taskProject => taskProject.Project.ProjectGroups.Select(pg => pg.ID),
                  group => group.ID,
                  (taskProject, group) => new { Task = taskProject.Task, Project = taskProject.Project, Group = group }
                 )
            select t;

Any assistance is appreciated!

You should filter instead of using explicit joins:
var tasks = _context.Task
    .Where(t => p.Project.ProgectGroups
        .SelectMany(pg => g.GroupMembers)
        .Any(u => u.Login == "username")
    );


So simple... I didn't know you could filter on those nav entities without including them first! Thanks!

Include is not for filtering. It is instruction which entities to load with main entity, so use it only in case the you need that loading.
